# REST API - drive logic by data provided or make separate endpoint/http method - best practice

Tags: api, rest, design-patterns, specifications

I am building my own implementation for file upload for my REST backend service, and I have `POST .../file` endpoint which has function of file upload initilalization.

It accepts some parameters regarding to settings for upcoming upload request(s) and perzists some data, so that is the reason i choosed `POST` HTTP method, and important one parameter is `file_id`.

Currently implemented logic is:

- if it is not provided, then new file is going to be uploaded (`file_id` will be obtained on return)
- if `file_id` is provided then informations regarding to status of file is returned (last sucessfully uploaded part, uplodaded parts, errors...)

Is it considered good approach to have this two actions under one endpoint ? Or should I split logic for "new file" and "continue with next part" into two endpoints (or separate HTTP method)

It uses same DTOs for request/response, only some fields are selectivelly not filled/returned.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it would be better to have one endpoint per action. So two endpoints would be highly desirable:

- POST: to upload file
- GET: you can appeal status of file through this method by `file_id`

Why? Because:

- Single responsibility principle. One method of API does just one action
- great separation of concerns
- clean and clear way of how to use of this API for consumers